# Error while using "wbt_conditional_evaluation" in R from WhiteboxTools package "whitebox"

Tags: r, raster-calculator, conditional, whitebox-tools

When I try to perform the conditional tools "wbt_conditional_evaluation" in R, I get this message error :

```
Error running WhiteboxTools (conditional_evaluation)
  whitebox.exe_path: "C:/R/R-4.1.1/library/whitebox/WBT/whitebox_tools.exe"; File exists? TRUE
  Arguments: --run=conditional_evaluation  --input="./acc_mean_mod_bol.tif" --output="./acc_mean_R_max.tif" --statement=value == 1 --true=./acc_mean_R_mod.tif --false=./acc_mean_R.tif --compress_rasters=FALSE -v --max_procs=-1

System command had status 101
conditional_evaluation - Elapsed Time: NA [did not run] "
```

Here the parameters :

```
wbt_conditional_evaluation(input = "./acc_mean_mod_bol.tif",
                           statement = "value == 1",
                           true = "./acc_mean_R_mod.tif",
                           false = "./acc_mean_R.tif",
                           output = "./acc_mean_R_max.tif")
```

The true and false inputs are flow accumulation rasters.

I use this tool to create the bolean raster (acc_mean_mod_bol.tif)

```
wbt_greater_than(input1 = "./acc_mean_R_mod.tif", 
                 input2 = "./acc_mean_R.tif", 
                 output = "./acc_mean_R_mod_bol.tif")
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? And is there a way to summarise these two operations by only using the function "wbt_raster_calculator". I'm trying to do this equivalent operation in ArcGIS raster calculator:

```
Con("acc_mean_R_mod.tif" > "acc_mean_R.tif","acc_mean_R_mod.tif","acc_mean_R.tif")
```

Comment: I don't like the look of the spaces in `--statement=value == 1` in the command. Can you try it with  `statement = "value==1"` in the R call (that is, *no* spaces inside the quotation marks)? If that works I'll write up an answer, if it doesn't work you might need to make a reproducible example.

Comment: I get a line saying "thread 'main' panicked at 'Unrecognized tool name conditional_evaluation.', whitebox-tools-app/src/main.rs:72:21" before getting your error. Are you seeing that? It looks like (for me) the R package and the underlying Whitebox Tools aren't compatible...

Comment: I just tried with a fresh install of `whitebox` R package from github and let it get the WBT tools package it wanted. Still failed. If you can edit the reproducible example into your Q its probably worth posting an issue to their issue tracker:  https://github.com/giswqs/whiteboxR/issues